# Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.4/electron-v9.4.4-darwin-arm64.zip

Tags: react-native, electron, apple-m1

I'm trying to install node modules for react native project in M1 macbook pro. While trying to run `npm install` or `yarn install` I'm having this error.

```
error /Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/electron: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/electron
Output:
HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.4/electron-v9.4.4-darwin-arm64.zip
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/got/source/as-stream.js:35:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at module.exports (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/got/source/get-response.js:22:10)
    at ClientRequest.handleResponse (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:155:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:476:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:381:22)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/business-hub/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:636:27)
```

I'm unable to find which of my packages are using electron for that I can not upgrade the version of electron.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases - shows releases only as far back as 11.4 - ?

Comment: Yes, as far I have found, react debugging tools require electron version 11.0.1 in m1 macs. I think I have found the ans. I will answer the question shortly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

React debugging tools require electron version 11.0.1 in m1 macs.
As described [here](https://github.com/mglukhovsky/react-devtools-components-blank) 
If using Yarn, you can add a resolutions entry to package.json specifying which version to install:

```
"resolutions": {
  "electron": "^11.0.1"
}
```

and then `yarn install`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is by upgrading electron. **But, if for some reason** you cannot do it (for example you need to build an old application on x86_64/i386 architecture that cannot be upgraded), you can run the Terminal using Rosetta:

1 - Locate Terminal on Finder (generally under Applications/Utilities)

2 - Right-click the Terminal icon and select Get Info.

3 - Check the **Open with Rosetta** option

After that, you can open the terminal and use the **arch** command to check if it is running in the correct architecture.

Then just run **npm install**.